# Can't connect to WiFi - CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT, status code = 1, ASSOC_REJECT 12 - wpa_supplicant

Tags: android, wifi, logcat, xiaomi, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to connect to my Wifi router with my Xiaomi Mi Max 2. I can connect to every router, but not to this one. Also, every other phone can connect to that router. I already tried changing protocols or resetting the router / phone.

Looking at logcat, I get the following:

wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Event ASSOC_REJECT (12) received
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=6c:99:24:0f:51:d2 status_code=1
wpa_supplicant: Continuous association failures - consider temporary network disabling
wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED [...]

Does anyone know what's going on and how I can solve this?

Best,
Trim